# Autolayout 16:9 animated GIF in Storyboard Xcode 10, iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, autolayout, storyboard

I'm having a Universal app and wanted to add a little tutorial. For that I have created a 16:9 animated GIF. I wanted to position that top/left or top/right. Text and buttons wherever space is left.

The image is initially 400x225, but I can accept any size, as long as 16:9 is kept.

I cannot figure out, how I could align that so that on phones it uses a smaller rect as on an iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the UIImageView to keep the same ratio.

You can do it using constraints, here’s how you should do it using your storyboard

[image: Adding aspect ratio constraint]

[image: Setting ratio multiplier]

If you want to stick it to the top left/right corner you should also add a constraint to the top of the superview- in order to stick it to the top, and a leading/trailing one to stick it to the left/right