# maintaining aspect ratio on launch screen

Tags: ios, screen, device, launch, aspect

I expect there's a simple answer here. If so, sorry and thanks.

I'm trying to make my launch screen for all the different iPad and iPhone sizes. On the launch storyboard I have two UIViews, one full size for the background (backView) and one in the shape of a square (squareView). I'm trying to keep the square from stretching (i.e. I'm trying to maintain a 1:1 aspect ratio) and make it 0.75 the width of whatever device the app runs on. I know that there will be varying amounts of space below, but how can I keep the square from distorting when I switch devices?
I've been researching the constraints and diddling with them for hours. I expect someone will tell me it's easy, just do ... what?

Comment: You can use auto layout to constrain the image view to maintain its aspect ratio.  Since the "width" is defined, you just need to ensure that the height is "undefined" and list the ratio constraint do its work

Comment: Check out this post- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484198/autolayout-169-animated-gif-in-storyboard-xcode-10-ios/53487893?noredirect=1#comment93884874_53487893

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, MadProgrammer. Do you mind elaborating. I've been changing constraints, equal widths, CTRL dragging between imageviews, trying suggested constraints, picking Aspect fill, Aspect fit, and so on. I just haven't hit the right thing to click where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I've centered my rect horizontally and vertically
[image: Centering]

Then I've set the rect's width to x0.75 of his superview
[image: Setting Width][image: Setting Width multiplier]

For the final step I'm setting his ratio to 1:1
[image: Setting ratio]
[image: Setting ratio multiplier]

That's it! Final result:
[image: final result]

Comment: Thank you for these detailed instructions. That worked. But a question: How would you place your red rectangle 1/3 of the way down, centered horizontally instead of fully centered?

Comment: You should set your `Align Center Y` constraint's **multiplier** to `3:2`

Comment: Niv, thank you. Terrific, clear explanations. I learned more from you than from reading the dozen sources I scoured on the Net.